# Trouble installing scrapy ("Segmentation fault (core dumped)")

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having issues installing scrapy with and without the sudo command. scrapy -V continues to return "command not found." Does anyone recognize this error? I'm using Lubuntu 18.04, Python 2.7.15rc1, pip 9.0.1

When I try to install Scrapy here are the outputs:

```
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/yelp_scraper_1-master/yelp_scraper$ pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/12/a6197eaf97385e96fd8ec56627749a6229a9b3178ad73866a0b1fb377379/Scrapy-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting queuelib (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/85/ae64e9145f39dd6d14f8af3fa809a270ef3729f3b90b3c0cf5aa242ab0d4/queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting w3lib>=1.17.0 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/94/40c93ad0cadac0f8cb729e1668823c71532fd4a7361b141aec535acb68e3/w3lib-1.19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/af/9d29e6bd40823061aea2e0574ccb2fcf72bfd6130ce53d32773ec375458c/pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/14/f4343239f955442da9da1919a99f7311bc5627522741bada61b2349c8def/lxml-4.2.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting parsel>=1.1 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/1a/9642a5ea68763d5e7c419df0873073e54bb23d0a8897d3c78e146dd6f355/parsel-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting service-identity (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/fa/995e364220979e577e7ca232440961db0bf996b6edaf586a7d1bd14d81f1/service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from Scrapy)
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from Scrapy)
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/44/25b7283e50585f0b4156960691d951b05d061abf4a714078393e51929b30/cssselect-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/e6/915a482dbfef98bbdce6be1e31825f591fc67038d4ee09864c1d2c3db371/cryptography-2.3.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting functools32; python_version < "3.0" (from parsel>=1.1->Scrapy)
Collecting pyasn1 (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/a1/7790cc85db38daa874f6a2e6308131b9953feb1367f2ae2d1123bb93a9f5/pyasn1-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/e1/5f9023cc983f1a628a8c2fd051ad19e76ff7b142a0faf329336f9a62a514/attrs-18.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/02/fa63f7ba30a0d7b925ca29d034510fc1ffde53264b71b4155022ddf3ab5d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/d5/d37fd731b7d0e91afcc84577edeccf4638b4f9b82f5ffe2f8b62e2ddc609/PyHamcrest-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/b6/84d0c863ff81e8e7de87cff3bd8fd8f1054c227ce09af1b679a8b17a9274/hyperlink-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/86/14c16bb98a5a3542ed8fed5d74fb064a902de3bdd98d6584b34553353c45/Automat-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/65/48c1909d0c0aeae6c10213340ce682db01b48ea900a7d9fce7a7910ff318/constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34; python_version < "3" (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting idna>=2.1 (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7 (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/dd/3e7a1e1280e7d767bd3fa15791759c91ec19058ebe31217fe66f3e9a8c49/cffi-1.11.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting ipaddress; python_version < "3" (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/d0/7fc3a811e011d4b388be48a0e381db8d990042df54aa4ef4599a31d39853/ipaddress-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from PyHamcrest>=1.9.0->Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/e8/570bb5ca88a8bcd2a1db9c6246bb66615750663ffaaeada95b04ffe74e12/setuptools-40.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Installing collected packages: queuelib, six, w3lib, enum34, idna, asn1crypto, pycparser, cffi, ipaddress, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, lxml, functools32, cssselect, parsel, pyasn1, attrs, pyasn1-modules, service-identity, setuptools, PyHamcrest, zope.interface, hyperlink, Automat, incremental, constantly, Twisted, PyDispatcher, Scrapy
Successfully installed Automat-0.7.0 PyDispatcher-2.0.5 PyHamcrest-1.9.0 Scrapy-1.5.1 Twisted-18.7.0 asn1crypto-0.24.0 attrs-18.2.0 cffi-1.11.5 constantly-15.1.0 cryptography-2.3.1 cssselect-1.0.3 enum34-1.1.6 functools32-3.2.3.post2 hyperlink-18.0.0 idna-2.7 incremental-17.5.0 ipaddress-1.0.22 lxml-4.2.5 parsel-1.5.0 pyOpenSSL-18.0.0 pyasn1-0.4.4 pyasn1-modules-0.2.2 pycparser-2.18 queuelib-1.5.0 service-identity-17.0.0 setuptools-40.2.0 six-1.11.0 w3lib-1.19.0 zope.interface-4.5.0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And with sudo:

```
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/yelp_scraper_1-master/yelp_scraper$ sudo pip install Scrapy
The directory '/home/owner/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/owner/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: Scrapy in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=13.1.0 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32; python_version < "3.0" in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from parsel>=1.1->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.2.1 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from PyHamcrest>=1.9.0->Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7 in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/owner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
```

I haven't had this problem with any other libraries, although I'm fairly new to Python. I also have 3.6 installed and wonder if there might be a conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try updating your pip version.

latest one is `pip 18.0`

Comment: Ok, I have done so and now get this: Successfully installed pip-18.0
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/yelp_scraper_1-master/yelp_scraper$ sudo pip install Scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/yelp_scraper_1-master/yelp_scraper$ pip install Scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main

Answer (score 0):

use this command to update your pip

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same problem today, although mine was with the Twisted package of scrapy. This is how i resolved it. First thing is to make sure that pip3 is installed on your device

```
sudo apt install pip3
```

Next thing i did is created a virtual environment using pipenv. If you don't already have this just do

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Next cd into the directory you want to work in and create a virtual environment

```
python3 -m pipenv --python 3.6
```

when you run that it will default to creating your environment with your default available **python version 3.6**. Activate your virtual environment

```
pipenv shell
```

And finally

```
pip install scrapy
```

you do not have to add the *3* to pip this time because it is already within a virtual environment where only the python version you used to create it is available. With this you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

just try command:

```
$pip3 install scrapy
```

and it will work :)